# How would I write a set of real numbers exclusive $\pi$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I hope I translate the question correctly.

I have to write down a set of real numbers exclusive $\pi$. So I have $x$ containing every real number as long the number isn't equal to $\pi$. My answer to this would look like that:

$$\{x\in \Bbb{R} |x\neq \pi\}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine. You can also write $\Bbb R\setminus\{\pi\}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Great minds think alike?

Comment: Can the set contain $-\pi$?

Answer (score 4):

That is fine. Also: $$\Bbb{R}\setminus \{\pi\}$$

Comment: Thank you! I just wasn't sure if I got this right.